# How to tidy up <div> tags?

Tags: html

What program is good to tidy up or highlight matching div tags?

I'm really confused at what div tags remain to be closed after nesting a few. I'm using notepad++ at the moment and it doesn't work brilliantly with `<div>` tags unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: i forgot to say, if the program works with rails .html.erb files that would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely consider using [HTML-Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

- Write a closing tag when you write
  the opening tag
- Use proper indentation

Answer (score 1):

Use [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/)

Comment: I've always used a mixture of VWD and Notepad++. Always worked nicely for me.

Comment: thanks, I might try this at some point. But for now the HTML tidy link did the trick.

Comment: It does so much work for you, I urge you to check it out.  Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Notepad++ are you using? I'm using a fairly recent one, and it hi-lights the closing/opening tags when you click on one.

Also, indentation is a big help. ..You could try cutting down on nested divs too. ;)

Comment: v5,4,1 actually it does hilight them, but I had to use html-tidy first for some of my div sections, as an over abundance of div tags confused it.